# DropDownList does not postback on SelectedIndex Changed

Tags: c#

I am attempting to get a DropDownList to AutoPostBack when the selected item is changed. I'm going a little stir-crazy as to why this isn't working.

Does anyone have any quick ideas?Please Help

Here is code:-

```
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_username" runat="server"
     AutoPostBack="True" 
     onselectedindexchanged="ddl_username_SelectedIndexChanged" 
     DataTextField="Shortname" DataValueField="ID">
     </asp:DropDownList>`

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      Bind_Users();
    }
 }

 private DataSet Bind_Users()
{
DataSet ds;
ds = cs.BindUsers();
if (ds.Tables[0] != null)
{
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ddl_username.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        ddl_username.DataTextField = "Shortname";
        ddl_username.DataValueField = "ID";
        ddl_username.DataBind();
        ListItem li = new ListItem();
        li.Text = "Select";
        li.Value = "-1";
        ddl_username.Items.Insert(0, li);
        ddl_username.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    //ddl_username.SelectedIndex = 0;
    //ddl_username.Text = "-----Select-----";
}
return ds;
}
```

Comment: Where is your implementation of the `ddl_username_SelectedIndexChanged` method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DropDownList does not postback on SelectedIndexChanged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000146/dropdownlist-does-not-postback-on-selectedindexchanged)

Comment: Please don't repeat your questions, amend your existing question

Comment: AFAIK, it won't post-back back by setting the `SelectedIndex` value programmatically (if that's what you were trying to do). Also, if the underyling values of the options are equal (regardless of their "index") I don't think it will fire the event when selecting a new index of the same value.

Answer (score 0):

on post back if you want to call `Bind_Users()` you should remove:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
  Bind_Users();
}
```